# Access level to translation files - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I generated a new entity

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:entity
```

when I want to update my database

> php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

I have this error

```
HP Fatal error:  Access level to Minn\AdsBundle\Entity\CountryTranslation::$id must be protected (as in class ..
```

I think there is a care with  **translation-bundle** exactly in :

**/NetBeansProjects/tuto/src/Minn/AdsBundle/Entity/CountryTranslation.php**

some idea my friends ?!!

Comment: Give us the declation of your entity CountryTranslation.

Comment: If you look into the created entity, could you tell us what's the type of `$id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to define the CountryTranslation:

```
<?php

namespace Minn\AdsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractPersonalTranslation;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="lookup_unique_idx", columns={
 *         "locale", "object_id", "field"
 *     })}
 * )
 */
class CountryTranslation extends AbstractPersonalTranslation {

    /*
     * Convenient constructor
     *
     * @param string $locale
     * @param string $field
     * @param string $value
     */
    /*public function __construct($locale, $field, $value) {
        $this->setLocale($locale);
        $this->setField($field);
        $this->setContent($value);
    }*/
    public function __construct() {
        /*this must be an empty one!*/
    }

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country", inversedBy="translations")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $object;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**My Entity CountryTranslation :**

```
<?php

namespace Minn\AdsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractPersonalTranslation;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="lookup_unique_idx", columns={
 *         "locale", "object_id", "field"
 *     })}
 * )
 */
class CountryTranslation extends AbstractPersonalTranslation {

    /*
     * Convenient constructor
     *
     * @param string $locale
     * @param string $field
     * @param string $value
     */
    /*public function __construct($locale, $field, $value) {
        $this->setLocale($locale);
        $this->setField($field);
        $this->setContent($value);
    }*/
    public function __construct() {
        /*this must be an empty one!*/
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country", inversedBy="translations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $object;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $locale;

/**
 * @var string
 */
 private $field;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $content;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set locale
 *
 * @param string $locale
 * @return CountryTranslation
 */
public function setLocale($locale)
{
    $this->locale = $locale;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get locale
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getLocale()
{
    return $this->locale;
}

/**
 * Set field
 *
 * @param string $field
 * @return CountryTranslation
 */
public function setField($field)
{
    $this->field = $field;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get field
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getField()
{
    return $this->field;
}

/**
 * Set content
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @return CountryTranslation
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get content
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * Set object
 *
 * @param \Minn\AdsBundle\Entity\Country $object
 * @return CountryTranslation
 */
public function setObject(\Minn\AdsBundle\Entity\Country $object = null)
{
    $this->object = $object;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get object
 *
 * @return \Minn\AdsBundle\Entity\Country 
 */
public function getObject()
{
    return $this->object;
}
```

}

Comment: This entity has been modified by the **php app/console generate:doctrine:entity** . I already experienced this kind of problem! You will find the correct entity definition on my answer!